# A countable expression expressible in $\mathrm{FO}_3$ with only one binary predicate?

Tags: co.combinatorics, lo.logic

Transitivity on a set is defined as follows 
$$\forall x \forall y\forall z( T(x,y) \land T(y,z) \rightarrow T(x,z))$$
Now if we wanted to count total number transitive relations which are defined on an arbitrary set, then we don't have a closed-form expression to do so. The sequence is given here https://oeis.org/A006905

My question is whether you know of any non-trivial expression, which requires at least three variables and one binary predicate and only uses universal quantifiers to be expressed (i.e requires $\mathrm{FO}_3$ with one binary predicate and only universal quantifiers), which has a closed-form counting expression. i.e a generator function that takes the cardinality of domain elements and maps them to the model count of the $\mathrm{FO}_3$ expression.

Through this investigation, I want to understand if there is a link between the countability of a certain process with its expressibility in first-order logic.

---

Example of what it means that a closed-form counting expression exists.
$$\forall_x\forall_y \mathsf{Smokes}(x) \land \mathsf{Friend}(x,y) \rightarrow S(y)$$ 
If we have $n$ individuals, then the number of models of this expression is given below. Notice this entire expression is expressed in $\mathrm{FO}_2$
$$a(n) = (3^{n}+4^{n})^{n}$$
Source:  https://www.ijcai.org/Proceedings/16/Papers/607.pdf

Comment: Also asked at [CSThE](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/46536/a-countable-expression-expressible-in-f03-with-only-one-binary-predicate).

Comment: What is FO3/FO2/FOL/F03/F02? doesn't occur in the linked paper.

Comment: @YCor $\mathrm{FO}_k$ is the fragment of first-order logic consisting of formulas that use at most $k$ distinct variables. (They may be reused.)

Comment: Alright, I found a simple answer. The number of equivalence relations on a set is given as $\sum_{k=0}^{n}  S(n, k)$. But I would still appreciate interesting answers. Also, I would be happy to know if there is some theory that tells us whether a closed-form for a sequence would exist or not.